# Do all of Murakami's works refer only to Western culture?

Tags: haruki-murakami

I just read Haruki Murakami's *The Wind-up Bird Chronicles*, and one thing that struck me was that despite the book being set in Japan and almost exclusively containing only Japanese characters, there are almost no references to Japanese culture (i.e music or literature etc.). Especially with regards to music, almost everybody is listening to American/European music. Is this the case with all his books? Or just an outcome of translation? Has the author ever talked about why?

Comment: I won't make this an answer because I can't cite specific references, but as a [big Murakami fan](http://popculturephilosopher.com/the-mysterious-disappearance-of-the-strangely-beautiful-woman/) who has read nearly all his (translated) work, I can't remember more than one or two places total where he ever refers to any Japanese music or literature (as opposed to the near constant stream of Western pop-culture references).  It does seem odd that every single person in his books seems so deeply steeped in non-Japanese culture.  Maybe that's true to life?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After glancing through a couple of on-line reviews and interviews like [this one](http://ajw.asahi.com/article/behind_news/people/AJ201409160009) , it seems like it's a choice by the author. Murakami's wife used to run a jazz club, and he seems to have a personal preference for Western music and literature, which has caused him some grief from Japanese critics of his work. As he says himself in the linked interview:

> Murakami doesn't read many of his Japanese contemporaries. Does he
>   feel detached from his home scene? "It's a touchy topic," he says,
>   chuckling. "I'm a kind of outcast of the Japanese literary world. I
>   have my own readers … But critics, writers, many of them don't like
>   me."

In [this article](http://ajw.asahi.com/article/behind_news/people/AJ201409160009) on translation, it says:

> In "Firefly," one of the short stories from "Blind Willow, Sleeping
>   Woman," Murakami writes, "What the hell do you think you're doing? I
>   asked myself. And what comes next? I hadn't the slightest idea. At
>   school I read Claudel's plays, and Racine's, and Eisenstein. I liked
>   their style, but that was it."
>
> “It is often said that Murakami’s Japanese is ‘honyakucho,’” says
>   producer Kawakami, meaning that it sounds almost as if someone has
>   translated English into Japanese. “Some Japanese find it appealing,
>   but others find that it makes his work difficult to get through. To a
>   certain extent, when compared to more vague Japanese, his words could
>   be simple to translate into English. But in making his images and
>   impressions clear, perhaps something of the original Japanese is not
>   completely expressed.

I've only read a couple of his books, but his taste for Western music seems to be a constant in his work.

Answer (score 1):

Murakami himself has spent many years of his life living in countries of the Western civilization, including but not limited to Greece, USA and Spain.

Also, Murakami grew up reading a lot of Western civilization books, from authors like Kurt Vonnegut, Richard Brautigan and Jack Kerouac. <sub>(Gewertz, Ken (December 1, 2005). "Murakami is explorer of imagination". Harvard Gazette. Retrieved 2008-04-24.)</sub>

Thus, it is only logical to be influenced by the Western Civilization.

I've read 8 of his books and yes, most of them refer to the Western civilization, but there are other references as well.

Here are some exceptions that I can remember:

- On *Kafka on the Shore*, two characters discuss [*The Miner*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Miner) by Natsume Sōseki.
- On *1Q84*, the japanese books mentioned were [*The Tale of the Heike*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Heike), [*Kojiki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kojiki) and if I'm not mistaken some quotes from Mao Tse-Tung's book (which is Chinese)

There is [a list](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Texts-films-referenced-Haruki-Murakamis/lm/R11KJ9IYS4W0ZV) on Amazon with the books that are mentioned on 1Q84.

Answer (score 1):

I have read a number of his works and as pointed out he rarely if ever references anything other than Western cultural influences.  I used to find it annoying because it did a very poor job of setting a mood or the tone of the moment because music for instance means very different things to different people depending on when the person originally heard the music or when/why they now enjoy listening to it.  So while one song may make one person sad it may make someone else happy.

I suspect Murakami's redundancy in this regard is a function of his writing style which is to essentially write variations of the same novel over and over again varying just the plot vehicle.  It's a known enough fact that there is actually a Murakami bingo game, so I don't see why he would ever begin to change and reference Eastern cultural items at this point.